# Install c++ compiler on windows without whole IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I already have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my computer. I do not have the Visual C++ Common Tools installed as I don't do any c++ dev work. I am trying to install some npm packages for my node.js work but I think they need a c++ compiler (installation fails with missing "CL.exe"). I don't want to install the full Visual C++ Common Tools as it appears to be 2GB and that seems pretty hefty for what I need (just a compiler).

Can I just get a compiler to install my npm packages without all the extra baggage?

I was looking at this http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools but when I try to install it it says I already have Visual Studio 2015 installed so it can't proceed.

Comment: You can try out VS15. It comes with a new installer, which allows specific installation only of components that you need, like C++.

Comment: Does it have support for node.js dev tools and typescript?

Comment: I don't think so. But you only need a compiler right? So you can install VS15, which will install the required compiler, and then go on and use VS2015

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Ok I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the VS15 installer forces me to install the "Visual Studio core  editor" which is a good 300-400MB and I can't specify just the C++ compiler. It's the same as the other VS2015 installer where I have to install the whole 2GB.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Sorry

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but if you have some capacity for expansion perhaps this is that time when investing in more storage might be appropriate, so that you don't have to worry over installing a component that you need.  I did that back in 2012 to create a 2 TB C: drive from an array of SSDs, and have never had to worry since.  Sure, it's expensive but that investment has paid off for me countless times.  It's just a thought.